# Derive Taylor series from Newton Polynomial

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

Here are the equations to derive Taylor series from Newton Polynomial.

$$\begin{align}
f(x) =& f(a) + \lim_{h \to 0} \sum_{k = 1}^\frac{x - a}{h} \frac{\Delta_h^k[f](a)}{k!h^k} \prod_{l = 0}^{k - 1} (x - a - lh)) \tag{1}\\\\
=& f(a) + \lim_{h \to 0} \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \frac{d^k}{dx^k} f(a) \prod_{l = 0}^{k - 1} (x - a - lh)) \tag{2}\\\\
=& f(a) + \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{d^k}{dx^k} f(a) \frac{(x - a)^k}{k!} \tag{3}
\end{align}$$

In $(2)$, when $k \to \infty$ and $l \to k - 1$, the term $(x - a - lh)$ should become

$$x - a - lh = x - a - \infty \cdot 0$$

$lh = \infty \cdot 0$ is undetermined. If we go back to $(1)$, when $k \to \frac{x - a}{h}$ and $l \to k -1$, we get

$$x - a - lh = h$$

The value of $(x - a - lh)$ is still different from $(x - a)$. Why we can still ignore $lh$ in $(3)$?

Comment: I'm not sure that it's valid to incorporate the limit into both the bounds and terms of the sum simultaneously. Otherwise, you could have $\displaystyle \underbrace{\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i}{n}}_{+\infty}=\sum^{\lim n}\lim\frac{i}{n}=\sum^\infty0=0$. I think the first step alone needs justification.

Comment: I also have doubts that the limit can be applied there. I got these equations from Chinese Wikipedia page: [泰勒級數](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B3%B0%E5%8B%92%E7%BA%A7%E6%95%B0#%E7%84%A1%E7%AA%AE%E7%B4%9A%E6%95%B8)